# AttributeError: 'Restaurant' object has no attribute 'describe_restaurant'

Tags: python

Q. Make a class called Restaurant. The **init**() method for Restaurant should store two attributes: a restaurant_name and a cuisine_type. Make a method called describe_restaurant() that prints these two pieces of information, and a method called open_restaurant() that prints a message indi- cating that the restaurant is open.
Make an instance called restaurant from your class. Print the two attri- butes individually, and then call both methods.

```
class Restaurant():
"""An attempt to model a restaurant"""

def __init__(self,restaurant_name,cuisine_type):
    """Initializing name and age attributes"""
    self.name = restaurant_name
    self.cuisine  = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        # Describes the restaurant name and cuisine
        print(self.name.title() + " serves " + self.cuisine + " food.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        # Opens the restaurant and welcomes customers.
        print(self.name.title() + " is now Open. \nCome. \nHave some delicious " + self.cuisine + " food.")

restaurant1 = Restaurant("big chill","italian")

print(restaurant1.name)
print(restaurant1.cuisine)
restaurant1.describe_restaurant()
```

I'm getting the output as :

```
big chill
italian
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rishabhchopra/Desktop/practice2/9-1.Restaurant.py", line 21, in <module>
    restaurant1.describe_restaurant()
AttributeError: 'Restaurant' object has no attribute 'describe_restaurant'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

**Q.Why is Python interpreting a method of my class as an attribute?**

Comment: So how do i fix this? Even though i have a method describe_restaurant , why is Python saying that  AttributeError: 'Restaurant' object has no attribute 'describe_restaurant' ?

Comment: Your indentation is really messed up, but it looks like you're nesting `describe_restaurant` within `__init__`.

Comment: Oh , okay. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your indentation really looks like this

```
 class Restaurant():
    """An attempt to model a restaurant"""

    def __init__(self,restaurant_name,cuisine_type):
        """Initializing name and age attributes"""
        self.name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine  = cuisine_type

        def describe_restaurant(self):
            # Describes the restaurant name and cuisine
            print(self.name.title() + " serves " + self.cuisine + " food.")

        def open_restaurant(self):
            # Opens the restaurant and welcomes customers.
            print(self.name.title() + " is now Open. \nCome. \nHave some delicious " + self.cuisine + "
```

you have accidentally nested your desired methods inside the `__init__` method, rendering them inaccessible. Fixing the nesting, you shouldn't have any issues.

```
 class Restaurant():
    """An attempt to model a restaurant"""

    def __init__(self,restaurant_name,cuisine_type):
        """Initializing name and age attributes"""
        self.name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine  = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        # Describes the restaurant name and cuisine
        print(self.name.title() + " serves " + self.cuisine + " food.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        # Opens the restaurant and welcomes customers.
        print(self.name.title() + " is now Open. \nCome. \nHave some delicious " + self.cuisine + "
```

Notice however, that a method is an attribute as mentioned by cdarke - the error message is being very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your indentation and it works fine:

```
class Restaurant():
    """An attempt to model a restaurant"""

    def __init__(self,restaurant_name,cuisine_type):
        """Initializing name and age attributes"""
        self.name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine  = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        # Describes the restaurant name and cuisine
        print(self.name.title() + " serves " + self.cuisine + " food.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        # Opens the restaurant and welcomes customers.
        print(self.name.title() + " is now Open. \nCome. \nHave some delicious " + self.cuisine + " food.")

restaurant1 = Restaurant("big chill","italian")

print(restaurant1.name)
print(restaurant1.cuisine)
restaurant1.describe_restaurant()
```

By the way, a method **is** an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Its just about indentation.

```
class Restaurant():

 def __init__(self,restaurant_name,cuisine_type):
      self.name = restaurant_name
      self.cuisine  = cuisine_type

 def describe_restaurant(self):
    # Describes the restaurant name and cuisine
    print(self.name.title() + " serves " + self.cuisine + " food.")

 def open_restaurant(self):
    # Opens the restaurant and welcomes customers.
    print(self.name.title() + " is now Open. \nCome. \nHave some delicious " + self.cuisine + " food.")
restaurant1 = Restaurant("big chill","italian")

print(restaurant1.name)
print(restaurant1.cuisine)
restaurant1.describe_restaurant()
```

Comment: It wasnt about me by the way just the copy paste.. :D